# appengine 1.7.2 err after upgrade

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I upgraded AE to 1.7.2 and now get the following error when first trying to access a page:

What can I do to get 1.7.2 working???

```
  Could not initialize class com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.RecordingData

Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class   
com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.RecordingData
at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recorder.makeAsyncCall(Recorder.java:300)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.call(AppstatsFilter.java:231)
```

Note: the ***"RecordingData"*** class that could not be initialized is in the ***appengine-api-labs.jar*** is definately in my build path only now it is not working.  I guess though that the ***Could not initialize class*** error means it's being found but not working.  the ***NoClassDefFoundError*** is misleading I suspect.

Comment: I suspect you have some classes built with an older SDK version. Have you tried cleaning up your project and recompiling it from scratch?

Comment: Yeah I cleaned the project and deleted everything generated in a build.  Same problem. I solved it though by going through the build path and deleting anything 1.7.1 or 1.7.1.1 and doing the same in the WEB-INF/lib.  It's weird, even though I had selected 1.7.2 as the SDK under Google in Eclipse, it was still launching as 1.7.1.  If I manually changed the arguments in the launch configuration, it complained that it should be 1.7.1 and reverted back.  I then deleted all 1.7.1 and 1.7.1.1 sdk's, reselected 1.7.2, cleaned everything again and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently, I started working on an existing AppEngine project which had been using the 1.7.1 API. I had a new eclipse setup using the newest plugin (1.7.2.1 at the time of writing).

In my case there was an older copy of the labs jar (`appengine-api-labs.jar`) in the build path. Deleting this and replacing it with the version from the AppEngine SDK in current use resolved the issue.

You'll find the labs jar in your eclipse plugins directory under: `appengine-java-sdk-[X.X.X.X]\lib\impl`).

Once you have replaced the jar do a clean build and you should be laughing.

Comment: I've downloaded my app from appengine.google.com using:
`appcfg.cmd -A <appname> -V <version> download_app c:\appname`
and trying to run it with:
`dev_appserver.cmd --port=8888 c:\appname\version`
and Im getting `WARNING: failed appstats: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/a
pi/memcache/MemcacheServiceException`

my problem is that I don't know what version of the SDK I built the original version in...and I dont have the source code anymore (which is why Im trying to reverse engineer it!)

Is there any log files or xml files that store the version used?